# As an addition to an aswered question.(Riemann integration)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

On [If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are Riemann integrable and $f(x)\leq h(x)\leq g(x)$, must $h(x)$ be Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85839/if-fx-and-gx-are-riemann-integrable-and-fx-leq-hx-leq-gx-must?rq=1) it has been proven that the assumption given is false, but if $f$ and $g$ are both integrable on $[a,b]$ and  $\int f(x)=\int g(x)$ , then is it now true that $h(x)$ is Riemann integrable? And if that happens to be the case, is $\int f(x)=\int h(x)$ on $[a,b]$?

Comment: Yes the integral of $f$ equals that of $h$.

Comment: Could you post a proof to that?

Comment: I think it is available on this site already. Let me search and post a link.

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390894/72031

Comment: Thanks, really helpful.